# Is there a way to clear invalid card reports in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, google-rich-snippets

Google Search Console offers a report on Rich Cards and notifications about cards that appear invalid. Notifications about invalid cards go back months.

Once I have fixed the error related to the card, is there a way to clear the specific invalid card notification?

I thought Google would do this automatically, but it doesn't seem to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no specific way to clear the reports as the google bot crawl over time and then only if they find the link with correct rich snippet only then they will remove the errors from the report.

> As google bot take up 30 time day (in my opinion ) for deep crawl roughly but may take longer it depends how frequently the content on your site is updated as it depends on the algorithm computer programs determine how often bots  should crawl each site [SEE HERE](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40392?hl=en).

AND

> 2.Ask Google to `RECRWAL` your URLs [here how](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en)
>   and only 10 URL you can request for indexing and these requests will go for indexing for that only particular link but not the links originated from that page.

for this you have to go the the search console and

> Fetch the link as google "Fetch as google" [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kXyc.jpg)
>   If you want you can request the URL with other links other links from page BUT ONLY 2 in a Day.
>   And also keep the guidelines in minds [by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769).